# JavaScript function and nested arrays question

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I would like some help please, you see I had to determine in exercise 6, if the the array included the name "waldo" and if my function would past the tests, it did and the console logged true for both tests. Now in exercise 7 it wants me to do this again, determine if the array contains "waldo" and if it does or doesn't my function should past these test. My issues if I tried so many different scenarios and I keep getting the console to log false for both tests or give me an error message "arrayOfNames" is not defined. I'm trying to use the hint and just call my containsWaldo function to no success. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here, I copied in the questions for both exercises to make it hopefully more clear. Thank you in advance.

```
----------------------------
console.log("Exercise Six");
// - Given the arrayOfNames, determine if the array contains the name "waldo".
// - The name waldo will be all lower-case.
// - If the array contains "waldo", return true.  If it does not, return false.
// - Hint: You don't have to write another loop, or copy-paste your previous function.
//   Just call your previous function, "contains," with the array and the name "waldo" and return the result.
// 
// Write your code here 

function containsWaldo(arrayOfNames) {
  return contains(arrayOfNames, "waldo");

}


//  -------TESTS---------------------------------------------------------------
//  Run these commands to make sure you did it right. They should all be true.
console.log("-----Tests for Exercise Six-----");
console.log("* Returns true when waldo is in an array");
console.log(containsWaldo(["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "waldo", "shaquon", "julie"]) === true);
console.log("* Returns false when waldo is not in the array");
console.log(containsWaldo(["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "shaquon", "julie"]) === false);


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
console.log("Exercise Seven");
// - Given the arrayOfNames, if the array contains waldo, then return "I found waldo!"
//   If the array does not contain waldo, then return "I couldn't find waldo..."
// - Hint: Don't actually search for waldo!  Just call your other function, "containsWaldo".
// 
// Write your code here 

function searchForWaldo(arrayOfNames) {
  return containsWaldo(arrayOfNames);

}
// my code here, will log false for both test cases


//  -------TESTS---------------------------------------------------------------
//  Run these commands to make sure you did it right. They should all be true.
console.log("-----Tests for Exercise Seven-----");
console.log("* Returns 'I found waldo!' when waldo is in an array");
console.log(searchForWaldo(["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "waldo", "shaquon", "julie"]) === "I found waldo!");
console.log("* Returns 'I couldn't find waldo...' when waldo is not in the array");
console.log(searchForWaldo(["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "shaquon", "julie"]) === "I couldn't find waldo...");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are returning false because you are comparing a boolean to a string value.

```js
console.log(searchForWaldo(["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "waldo", "shaquon", "julie"]) === "I found waldo!");
console.log(searchForWaldo(["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "shaquon", "julie"]) === "I couldn't find waldo...");
```

The comparison you're trying to do is:

```js
console.log(searchForWaldo(["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "waldo", "shaquon", "julie"]) === true);
console.log(searchForWaldo(["bob", "nancy", "john", "shawnie", "shaquon", "julie"]) === true);
```

Even so, you need to log a string to the console and not the value of the boolean.

Comment: Thank you, I was having a hard time with this.

Answer (score 0):

What it need to do is written right here:

```
// - Given the arrayOfNames, if the array contains waldo, then return "I found waldo!"
//   If the array does not contain waldo, then return "I couldn't find waldo..."
```

```
function searchForWaldo(arrayOfNames) {
  return containsWaldo(arrayOfNames) ? 'I found waldo!' ? 'I couldn't find waldo...'
}
```

Moreover there is not a single nested array in this code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Exercise Six
const contains = (arr, needle) => arr.includes(needle);    

// Exercise Seven
const contains = (arr, needle) => arr.includes(needle) ? "I found waldo!" : "I couldn't find waldo...";
```

[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation.